# How to debug Leshan Code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am referring to Leshan Code [Leshan Server](https://github.com/eclipse/leshan). I have successfully downloaded, Compiled and even built JAR file using maven command line.

I have followed all the steps but i am unable to make the code run from Eclipse. I am unable to find which option should i choose in "Run As" menu of Eclipse so as to make .jar binary from Leshan code via Eclipse.

The Jar Binary gets created if i use the steps mentioned in above URL via command line, but i want to debug the same code via Eclipse.

Can any one please help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to import the Leshan projects using the "Import Existing Maven Projects" wizard.

[image: Import Existing Maven Projects]

Select the location where you have cloned Leshan locally (you may also want to do the repository cloning right from Eclipse using EGit)

[image: Select the location of Leshan projects]

Once the projects are imported (the Maven plug-in may complain about a missing "replacer" plug-in but that won't prevent you from debugging), the entry point to launch the Leshan server is the Leshan standalone class.

[image: Debug Leshan]

You now have Leshan running at http://localhost:8080 and you can debug it!

Comment: Fantastic.. Thanks a lot for your guidance!!! This is what i wanted, Appreciate your effort